# Silverlight4: How to drag one UserControl from one Canvas to another Canvas using MouseDragElementBehavior

Tags: silverlight

I define a custom UserControl named Icon and two custom Class named desktop inherited from Canvas in Silverlight 4
I want to drag one Icon from one Desktop to another using MouseDragElementBehavior. Of course the two Desktop must know about the drag event so that they can do some changes. 
So can the other Desktop know the icon is exactly dragged to it? Or how can I inform the Desktop that a Icon has been dragged to it.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a AllowDrop property that you can set to true. Then create an event handler for the Drop event.

```
<Canvas VerticalAlignment="Top" AllowDrop="True" Drop="Canvas_Drop"></Canvas>
private void Canvas_Drop(object sender, System.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
{

}
```